# ¿Cómo realizar un cuadrado con terminación diagonal? CSS3

Tags: css, css3

Comunidad, tengo una duda, ¿Cómo es posible realizar un cuadrado con inicio o terminación perpendicular en CSS3 como en el diseño de Microsoft?

[image: Cuadrado con terminación o inicio perpendicular]

Comment: Prueba aquí [css3generator.com](http://css3generator.com) con Transform, es una herramienta muy sencilla que me agiliza mucho el trabajo.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar `background-image` con `-webkit-linear-gradient` para realizar este efecto.

Además, parece ser que es compatible con casi todos los navegadores (las nuevas versiones). Puedes ver todas las compatibilidades [aquí](http://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-linear-gradient).

```css
#diagonal{
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(280deg, blue 45%, black 50%);
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="diagonal"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente con [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) y la función [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform#rotate):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

header {
  margin: -50px;  
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #0078d7;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>  
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Cuida. La etiqueta `</header>` la has puesto como `</<header>`.

Comment: @Error404 - Gracias